# Can data access tokens be generated using Databricks Community Edition?

Tags: databricks, databricks-community-edition

I'm trying to create an access token using Databricks community edition but the option doesn't seem to be available.  Can an access token be created in the community edition or is this not available?

This is what [the guide](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/api/latest/authentication.html) shows:
[image]

This is what I'm seeing:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I still don't know if an access token can be generated from the community edition but I was able to solve the problem by upgrading and setting up an instance on Amazon.  The access token option is now available on the upgraded instance.

[image]